# Swift - UITableView inserting rows causing dead-lock

Tags: swift, uitableview, search, rows, deadlock

I am doing a search on large number of text files on a background thread, going back to main thread to append the results to an array, and then insert rows to table view:

```
func searchFor(_ text: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        for path in self.allPoemsPaths {
            for poem in Helper.getPoems(filePath: path) {
                if poem.body.applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)!.contains(text) {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.searchResults.append(poem)

                        self.resultsTable.beginUpdates()
                        self.resultsTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.searchResults.count-1, section: 0)], with: .none)
                        self.resultsTable.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With large number of search results, the view is locked/unresponsive for a time depending on the search (for common words, it locks up for more than 3 sec). I am aware of that the rows insertion must be carried out on the main thread and this what makes the hanging.

I thought of an idea: insert the onscreen rows, and insert the rest as the user scrolls down. I couldn't figure how to do it in code.

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: It's much more efficient to append all items to `searchResults` and then insert all rows at once. By the way the `begin-/endUpdates` lines are pointless. They have no effect for a single insert operation (even in a loop).

Comment: There are 100000+ text files, with some of them amounting to more than 500 lines each. Sure it will consume time to populate the array before inserting them all at once in the table rows. In this time, user will see nothing! Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Parsing text files with `contains` is  extremely expensive and slow. You should use something like Spotlight to index the files.